# Clojurescript : two dots in expression

Tags: clojurescript

I am working with Om and I didn't fully understand the following expression :

```
 (.. e -target -checked)
```

Here, "e" is a javascript event, and "-target -checked" is a way to access properties, if I understood well. But what about the two dots at the beginning ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That's one of the forms for clojurescript interop.

The most basic one is

```
(.method object) ; Equivalent to object.method()
(.-property object) ; Equivalent to object[property]
```

In order to access several nested properties, there is a shortcut with the `..` operator, so that you can do:

```
(.. object -property -property method)
(.. object -property -property -property)
```

Instead of:

```
(.method (.-property (.-property object)))
(.-property (.-property (.-property object)))
```

And the code results in a cleaner more readable expression. As you can see, the parallel is that the form is the same as normal interop but without the dot, so that property access turns into `-prop` and method calls turn into `method` (no dot).

Those forms above are equivalent to this JS forms:

```
object[property][property][method]()
object[property][property][property]
```

Read up this good post to learn more about clojurescript's javascript interop forms:  http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/

Comment: From the link @joaquin shared, you can also use the form: `(aget js/object "prop1" "prop2" "prop3")`

Comment: I think you mean `object["property"]` instead of `object[property]` (i.e., the former includes quotes).